# Unknown root certificate in keychain

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

While working on something unrelated I had to look into my keychain access app and noticed that I have a self-signed root certificate in there with a name from some person that I don't even know.

I have no idea where this certificate came from and what it means. How can I figure out what put this certificate there? What can it be used for?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the certificate!